# Can I use itembased Hadoop implementation for userbased implementation by exchanging the itemid column with userid?

Tags: hadoop, mahout, recommendation-engine

I want to do a benchmark using userbased recommendation. So can I just exchange the column value of `itemID` and `userID`?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite. You can exchange users and items, but then you are recommending users to items, not items to users. But yes it would be based on user-user similarity since you are using users as items.

There is no user-similarity-based implementation on Hadoop per se.